# AsynchTask and Command Pattern?

Tags: android

Can we consider an AsynchTask in Android like realization of a command pattern? Does anyone uses pure Command pattern in Android? If yes - can you share a sample or a link?

http://androidforums.com/application-development/386207-what-design-patterns-do-you-use.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to answer the question might be:

Wikipedia says: *In object-oriented programming, the command pattern is a design pattern in which an object is used to represent and encapsulate all the information needed to call a method at a later time. This information includes the method name, the object that owns the method **and values for the method parameters**.*

AsyncTask doesn't encapsulate values for the method parameters so, the answer to your question can be 'no'.

I fail to see any practical value of the question though and what is 'pure' command pattern I don't know either.

Comment: pure Command -> I mean usual Command pattern.Is it good practice to use this pattern in Android?

Comment: Why not? I believe, using GoF patterns is always a good practice. Are there examples proving the opposite though?